# use multiple transform: translate(X, Y) on same element

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, css-transforms

i have an image of one of those step by step poster and i placed it in another div to hide all the excess on the poster image and hid the overflow so it would only show one step at a time.

```
transform: translate(-23px, -40px);
transform: translate(25px, -165px);
transform: translate(5px, -325px);
transform: translate(-230px, -420px);
transform: translate(-442px, -325px);
transform: translate(-485px, -175px);
transform: translate(-440px, -40px);
transform: translate(-220px, -10px);
```

Comment: Do you have more of an example of what you're trying to do? Is this one of those things, where you can click a forward or backwards button and it will "scroll" the image in that direction and then you see a new image?

Comment: No but thats a good idea. i took a how to put up a tent image that had top center a tent collapsed then going in a clock motion the two steps to put it up, then bottom center had it up and continued with the steps putting it down until it was back at the top. instead of a gif, which was un-available i was going to use transitions. i made a div to hold the image and made the image three times bigger than the div(one for the middle, left, and right) and hid the overflow. then i just transitioned from one step to the next all the way round but it doesn't work if you just list the transitions

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with css animate but it was still very easy. use @keyframes and name your function then put the percent at which it runs the transform. finally just call the function you want and add animate with the property of function name, time to cycle, and number of cycles.

```
@keyframes MARY-GO-ROUND{
   0%, 100% {transform: translate(-23px, -40px);}
   12% {transform: translate(25px, -165px);}
   24% {transform: translate(5px, -325px);}
   36% {transform: translate(-230px, -420px);}
   48% {transform: translate(-442px, -325px);}
   60% {transform: translate(-485px, -175px);}
   72% {transform: translate(-440px, -40px);}
   84% {transform: translate(-220px, -10px);}
}
img#image_go_round{
   animation: MARY-GO-ROUND 20s infinite;
}
```